# How to identify if the user blows air in their mic in android?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to identify when the user blows air on their mic through media recorder but unfortunately i am not able to differentiate. Is there any way to identify or differentiate between voice and air blow in android. Please some one help me here. Thanks in advance.